# get atom feed and display in html (google-api)

Tags: php, curl, google-api, atom-feed, google-finance-api

Can someone help me out on this.
I have a problem with the return results from an google-api call

I want to echo them back as html, but firefox keeps displaying a feed page.

In IE, I get an error saying that an xml document can only contain one toplevel element
wich must be the atom "feed" element, so I don't get that.

What can I do to improve on this?

```
$response= curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// Parse the response
$response= simplexml_load_string($response);

foreach($response->entry as $position)
{
    echo "position: " . $position->title . "<br />";
    //next would be the stockvalue, but I don't yet know how to get that

}
```

**edit**

```
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
    "GData-Version: 2",
);

 $ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios/1/positions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

**edit**
I saw my mistake
I did not use

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: Can you provide the API call URL, or the XML response you get? That could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `var_dump()` your `$response` and look what data you have inside.

And I will use `file_get_contents()` instead of `CURL`.

Comment: still the same data, I don't know whats going on
They show the same samplecode on different sites/tuts